# how to fix a facebook Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException problem

Tags: facebook, api, curl

I've got this error coming from facebook, from time to time:

`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: connect() timed out! thrown in /var/www/html/xxx/facebook/src/facebook.php on line 614`

it breaks my site.

this is the code from facebook.php

```
if ($result === false) {
  $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error'      => array(
      'message' => curl_error($ch),
      'type'    => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
  curl_close($ch);
  throw $e;
}
```

is there a way to fix this? or at lease to degrade gracefully ?
thanks

i am thinking to arr a `return false;` if the `$result === true`
but i don't know if that will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception to avoid the immediate Fatal Error kill, but you still need to 
adjust to facebook data not being available. See http://www.php.net/catch

```
try {
    // facebook code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // maybe something more graceful...
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
// regular execution continues.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem since yesterday on all my apps (around 20). It works normal most of the time, but then sometimes instead of loaded page this is what users get (I think it's because of using $me  = $facebook->api('/me'); - after I removed that I haven't got that error yet, but the problem now is that I need this in order to get users data).